# Knockout binding using object in data-bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

i was trying to figure a way to bind some values as object to an element

It works if i do binding like this

```
var viewModel = { 
    someObj: ko.observable(),
    textBox: { 
        value: ko.observable('val'),
        attr: { title: 'Test', placeholder: 'Test' },
        style: { width: '100px' }
    }
}

<input type="text" data-bind="value: textBox.value, attr: textBox.attr, style: textBox.style />
```

But is there any way to bind like this

```
<input type="text" data-bind="bindFrom: textBox" />
```

I tried to create a customBinding "bindFrom" using ko.bindingHandlers
but dont know how to trigger these individual bindings manually.

Looking for some help!.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're stating how you want to solve some problem you have by using a custom binding.  Instead, you should state your core problem.  What is it you're trying to do?  And then what is your reasoning for taking this approach?  There is likely a much simpler solution to your original problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My actual situation is lil bigger to explain. but in small, i have a 'renderHTML(vm)' function which takes 'vm' as parameter then it constructs HTML input (can be multiple depending on the props in vm) with those bindings init. So instead of looping each prop im looking for a custom binding (or something else) which will do same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading knockout.debug.js

i have created this custom binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bindFrom = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
        ko.utils.objectForEach(value, function (bindName, bindValue) {
            bindObj = ko.bindingHandlers[bindName];
            ko.utils.objectForEach(bindObj, function (type, fn) {
                if (typeof fn == 'function')
                    fn(element, function () { return bindValue }, allBindings);
            });
        });
    }
};
```

which is **working fine** like expected.

check it out at **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26eca3rs/4/)**